# Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android

I am having this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.justedhak.www.i/com.je.www.i.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.justedhak.www.i.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar
```

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void initToolbars() {

        Toolbar toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_settings:
                        // TODO
                        break;
                    // TODO: Other cases
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        toolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

this is gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Toolbar is not part of the v4 support libs, it's in v7.

So change your xml to :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Comment: I want to the toolbar bottom but its not geeting bottom can you know why ?

Comment: I don't understand your question .

Comment: if you notice in my layout xml, I am trying to create a toolbar ,ok ? the toolbar is created top of the app, I want to create the toolbar at the bottom .. how to do that ?

Comment: Add bottom gravity : android:layout_gravity="bottom"